# Why does Chrome slap a body at the top of my HTML, and then give me a seemingly bogus err msg?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I am replacing the html on my page when I return dynamically generated html from a REST method called via Ajax like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name = "QuadrantData")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
{
    _unit = unit;
    _beginDate = begdate;
    _endDate = enddate;
    string beginningHtml = GetBeginningHTML(); // This could be called from any page to reuse the same "header"
    string bodyBeginningHtml = GetBodyBeginHTML();
    string top10ItemsPurchasedHtml = GetTop10ItemsPurchasedHTML();
    string pricingExceptionsHtml = GetPriceComplianceHTML();
    string forecastedSpendHtml = GetForecastedSpendHTML();
    string deliveryPerformanceHtml = GetDeliveryPerformanceHTML();
    string endingHtml = GetEndingHTML();
    String HtmlToDisplay = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}",
        beginningHtml,
        bodyBeginningHtml,
        top10ItemsPurchasedHtml,
        pricingExceptionsHtml,
        forecastedSpendHtml,
        deliveryPerformanceHtml,
        endingHtml);

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            HtmlToDisplay,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "text/html"
        )
    };
}
```

It is called from within the ready function (when a button is clicked) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#btnGetData",
        function () {
            var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
            var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
            var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
            $("#newhourglass").removeClass("hide");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:
                    '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues
new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
            .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
            .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
            .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                cache: false,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: false
                },
                success: function (returneddata) {
                    $("body").html(returneddata);
                    $("#newhourglass").addClass("hide");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error in ajax call to QuadrantData');
                    $("#newhourglass").addClass("hide");
                }
            });
        });
        . . .
```

The string named "HtmlToDisplay" ("returneddata" in the Ajax call) begins like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"><title>eServices Reporting - Customer Dashboard</title><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css\"><script src= . . .
```

As you can see, it does not begin with a spurious/superfluous "body" tag, but when I look at the page source via F12 in Chrome Dev Tools, the first thing (above "`<!DOCTYPE html>`" and the rest) is "`<body>`"

Why is `<body>` there?

In the console there in Chrome Dev Tools, there is an err msg "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var*"

When I 2-click that, it takes me to the "`<body>`" tag.

So not only do I wonder why "`<body>`" is there, but also why Chrome Dev Tools apparently thinks it's a token named "var"

I have painstakingly compared the contents of "HtmlToDisplay" with the html page source prior to the attempt to replace the original html, and see no significant differences (just escape ("\") symbols for strings, and such).

Why might it be that Chrome slaps a `<body>` tag at the top of my HTML, and why does it take me there when 2-clicking the "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var*" console err msg?

### UPDATE

Weird as it is, or seems, at least, I don't think the superfluous/spurious `<body>` tag is really the problem, because for some reason it is on the unmodified page, too - before I even click the button to replace the html, the page (View page source) begins:

```
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

### UPDATE 2

This superfluous/spurious "`<body>`" tag apparently came from _Layout.cshtml, which was:

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p> &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - PRO*ACT USA</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

When I removed both (opening and closing) `<body>` tags, the mystery was resolved - they no longer appear in the html.

I still have the same basic problem, though; it's just that the err msg in the console now goes to an empty line above "`<!DOCTYPE html>`" when 2-clicked.

Why does the html start with an empty line, and is this potentially problematic?

The initial blank line of row 1 of the doc appears both in View page source and in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: The question reads like you're inserting an entire document html with a second BODY inside an existing BODY. It sounds like a very strange thing to do since BODY is not the document root. You may want to use `$('html')` instead.

Comment: Do you mean do this:

$("html").html(returneddata);

...instead of this:

$("body").html(returneddata);

? It makes no difference - the results are identical.

Comment: Huh, that could be a bug in jQuery because the vanilla js appears to be working here: `document.documentElement.innerHTML = newHTML`

Comment: Anyway, see the existing answers: [Replace HTML page with contents retrieved via AJAX](//stackoverflow.com/a/11984907)

Comment: Also: [Does the DOCTYPE declaration have to be the first tag in an HTML document?](//stackoverflow.com/a/69831)

Comment: *"Why does the html start with an empty line, and is this potentially problematic?"* Because that's what your server returns, and no it isn't problematic. The debugger taking you to the blank space isn't indicating that there's an error there, it just wasn't able to locate where the code that threw the error is located for some reason, likely due to it not being part of the original page.

Comment: Also, due to your poor editing practices your question is now very unclear and doesn't match the title.

Comment: If you are rendering the whole webpage through Javascript, why don't you just navigate to another page? AJAX is for updating part of the webpage to save bandwidth and resources of reloading the whole page.

Comment: That's a thought.

Comment: In HtmlToDisplay, why are there backslashes in front of all the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` I don't think it has anything to do with HTML, but instead its something about **JS** code that's embedded in your HTML.

Are you missing a semicolon / bracket / end of statement before declaring the next `var`? I'll suggest that you copy the complete `returneddata` to your favorite editor and search for all `var`s to see if there is any issue on **previous line**.